# JQuery can't find element in XMLDocument only in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, xmldocument

I have a call to a webservice that is returning the next raw response

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 1516
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Date: Fri, 12 Feb 2016 10:28:58 GMT

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <OperationListResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <OperationListResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <a:data>123</a:data>
                <a:operation_id i:nil="true"/>
                <a:status>OK</a:status>
            </OperationListResult>
        </OperationListResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

When I get this XML in my javascript code, I'm trying to read the element "status" using the next code:

```
//dataResponse is my javascript valid XMLDocument
x = $(dataResponse).find('status').text();
```

And instead of getting "OK", I'm getting "". This only happens in Firefox. The weird thing is that it works great in Chrome, Opera, Edge and Safari.
While debugging in Firefox, making a watch to the dataResponse object, I can actually see that the node "status" has the value "OK".

[image]

Any clue on how to solve this issue?

Edit:
I've tried doing the changes that Jai suggested, and I got weird results from firefox. If I Watch a variable that makes the "find", I can see the text. If i try to find by directly typing the "$(dados).find('a\:status').text()", i cant see any results.
Firefox watch panel:
[image]

Chrome watch panel:
[image]

Comment: `x = $(dataResponse).find('a\\:status').text();` try with escaping the colon.

Comment: Maybe you need to share some more code, with the part of the request and how you read and parse it.

Comment: @Jai it has a lot of sense. Add an answer, for sure it will be checked as correct.

Comment: I'd go with Jai's comment but then i'm really not sure why your posted code was working on other browsers....?

Comment: I don't see how this works in any browser, given the tag is `<a:status />`, not `<status />`...?

Comment: ok, I've escaped the the a:status. Got great response from Firefox, it did found the element.But now Chrome can't find it. I can't comprehend why this happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery probably doesn't have anything to do with this, besides being the wrong tool for the job. For element lookups it mostly delegates to [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). XML Documents have namespaces, and [selectors have special handling](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#type-selectors) for namespaces.

But namespace shorthands require that mappings from shorthand to namespace URIs are first declared. E.g. XPath lookups do that through [Document.evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate)'s namespace resolver argument and selectors in stylesheets retrieve them from [@namespace declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@namespace)

`querySelectorAll` does not take arguments that support such namespace resolution, therefore only no-namespace, default-namespace and any-namespace selectors can be specified.

In other words, it's not possible to match a `status` element in the `a -> http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/` namespace with a `a|status` selector through `querySelectorAll`, in fact, it should actually [throw an exception](https://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/selectors-api2/#resolving-namespaces). And `a:status` would just be a pseudo element selector that's not known to the browser.

A more generic `*|status` selector should match it, but it could potentially overmatch by also selecting status elements from other namespaces.

If you want to do namespace-aware traversal in XML documents you probably should use XPath instead.

Answer (score 2):

As i posted in comments to escape the `:` with `\\`:

```
x = $(dataResponse).find('a\\:status').text();
```

Still, it does not make any sense, that worked in other browsers but firefox.

Comment: This just worked great in Firefox, but in Chrome I'm getting now a x="", in the "watch" panel. Also, tried a:status in Chrome and it didn't worked too.